# Rails load path questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Say I have some custom classes that don't belong in models, controllers etc, I should put this in /lib correct?

In rails < 3 I would add this directory to my loadpath and in rails 3+ I would add this to my autoload_path. Is this correct?

Now say I have some classes that extends already defined classes. Where should I put this so its run on startup. Forexample say I want to add the method 'foo' on String.

```
class String
  def foo
    'foo;
  end
end
```

Where should I put this class so it's defined on startup?

Another weird bug I have is when I try to namespace classes in lib.

```
module MyProject
 class Foo
 end
end
```

Now in a console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :004 > MyProject::Foo
LoadError: Expected /Users/me/workspace/my_project/lib/foo.rb to define Foo
 from /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:492:in `load_missing_constant'
 from /Users/rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:183:in `block in const_missing'
```

I keep getting this error. How can I load this file?

Answer (score 8):

In rails 3, the autoload path is disabled in the config/application.rb

```
#config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

You have to de-comment this line if you want to load code from lib dir.

Answer (score 3):

You can generally put the class files wherever you want, for example you could put them in app/others and add the directory to your load_path in Rails 2 or autoload_path in Rails 3.

To extend already defined classes you'll probably want to put the files in your config/initializers directory.

To fix the bug you mention you should probably define the Foo class in your foo.rb file, and make sure that the module names match up (Bags and MyProject).

The reason the name was changed to autoload is that [the classes in autoload_paths are actually getting autoloaded, not simply loaded](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/01/17/ruby-autoloading-explained/).  This is the difference between using 'autoload' and 'require' in Ruby.

Comment: Bags was actually a typo. Still getting that error. Is there anywhere else I can put files that I want autoloaded like initializers?. Not sure why Rails3 calls it autoload when it only autoloads if the constant has not been defined

Comment: Along with autoload_paths you can use autoload_once_paths that allow you to define directories that will only be loaded once when you start Rails.  Make sure that between testing you are entirely restarting your console or rails app - even if you are in development, as initializers and autoload_only_once paths will only be loaded once - even in development.

Comment: The thing that is really confusing is that "autoload" doesn't really auto load anything. It just adds to the classpath. Everything in config/initializers actually auto loads .. ie runs on startup

Comment: I've appended my answer with an explanation of 'autoload' vs 'require'. Hopefully this will shed some light on the difference.